# Jekyll permalinks based on layout

Tags: jekyll

I'm working on my first Jekyll website, and I'm expecting to have a bunch of different things there such as blog posts, a linked list, photo albums, and so on, and have thus prepared a whole bunch of layouts to suit each of them.

So I was wondering if there was a way I could get Jekyll to set permalinks based on the layout, so that posts have their permalink automatically set to `/layout_name/yy/mm/post_name`.

I've been digging around [Jekyll's permalink documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/) and various Jekyll tutorials, but to no avail, and now I'm wondering if it's even possible to automate this.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the principle that each type of page/post can be in a specific folder (eg: /albums for you photo albums), you can have a look at [default configuration](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/#front-matter-defaults).

This can help you to set default `permalink` for a folder in `_config.yml` :

```
defaults:
  -
    scope:
      path: "albums" 
      type: "posts"
    values:
      permalink: "my/albums/"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I was looking for! (I'd upvote your answer, but don't have the needed "reputation" to do so, apparently.)

Comment: Ok that's it ! Happy Jekyll !

Comment: Thanks! It really has been a lot of fun working with it so far.

Comment: I dunno what's gone wrong, but I just can't get this to work. I've got the following in my front matter, 

`defaults:
  -
    scope:
      path: "posts"
    values:
      permalink: "posts/:year/:month/:title"`

but it still generates permalinks with the default format. Any idea what could be the issue? Also, just realized I hadn't mentioned that I'm running this on Windows, if that could be part of the issue.

Comment: Are you sure of your `path: "posts"`? This target `_posts/posts` folder.

Comment: My bad, I'd misinterpreted the path variable. Thanks, it's all fine now!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do something similar and ended up writing a small plugin that allows you to use any Front Matter variable in the permalink setting. You can find the plugin with a usage example on [GitHub](https://github.com/NiklasEi/jekyll_custom_permalink).

This way you don't have to use the folder structure and can build the paths to each page in a collection using any Front Matter (including `layout`) from the files.