# defining Directory specific permalinks in the config file in jekyll

Tags: jekyll

Im working on a site using jekyll. I want to change the url of all pages in a directory without having to write permalink: url in every front matter.

I have a directory jobs in pages

```
 pages
    jobs
       example.markdown
       otherexample.markdown
```

I want all pages in jobs to have the url /talent/filename.
I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27984905/jekyll-permalinks-based-on-layout) and tried this:

```
defaults:
-
   scope:
      path: 'pages/jobs'
      type: 'pages'
   values:
      permalink: 'talent/:slug'
```

The result in the _site directory was this:

```
 Talent
    :slug
        index.html
```

with the other pages just vanishing entirely. I have tried a number of the variables listed [here](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/#template-variables), with similar results. Does anyone know what is going on?

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>You forgot a trailing slash '/' in the path.</strike>

the example below should give you the desired generated output.

if you have set `permalink: pretty` globally it would create a folder for each title with an index.html inside

if not just the files like yourtitle.html

```
defaults:
-
   scope:
      path: "pages/jobs"
      type: "pages"
   values:
      permalink: /talent/:basename.html
```

Comment: I tried that, but all that happens is that the files in jobs go back to having their path define their url (so site/pages/jobs/thetitle.html)

Comment: Its as if Jekyll is ignoring the colons. Ive been playing around a bit more with permalink, and the variables do not seem to be working.

Comment: thank you very much, now it is working fantastically. I can go home from work now!

Comment: Sorry, the trailing slash was an error. I updated the configuration snippet. I tested it locally with the same structure like you and it gives me the desired output.

Comment: for some reason the :slug variable doesn't work for me, ive tried to do this on other jekyll pages and it has worked there. I think ive probably accidentally changed something somewhere.