# How to add permalink and variables globally to Jekyll pages inside a specified directory

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I'm setting up a website with multi language support.

In the root directory I have one or more directories based on the language locale, e.g.: /en /it

I'm trying to set one language as default and let Jekyll generate its pages in the root of the `_site` directory, by setting the defaults section in _config.yml as described below. Other directories will be generated as usual.

I don't want:

- to use a plugin since it have to work also with GitHub pages
- to set a `lang: en` variable in each page front-matter but setting it globally in _config.yml instead if possible
- put a load of files/directories in the root directory, just the various en, it, fr etc (if not having something like described below, but using a master `pages` directory).

I tried various solutions, including:

- using collections: it works as expected with the example below but I don't want to use them for various reasons, like not having sitemap plugin working with them
- using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36456844/defining-directory-specific-permalinks-in-the-config-file-in-jekyll), but it doesn't work with multiple pages with same name and other types of documents

This works with collections with an `_en` directory in the root:

```
collections:
  en:
    output: true
    permalink: /:path

defaults:
  ...
  - scope:
      path: ""
      type: "en"
    values:
      layout: "default"
      lang: "en"
      permalink: /:path
```

Not this, IMHO as it should be for pages:

```
defaults:
  ...
  - scope:
      path: "en"
      type: "pages"
    values:
      layout: "default"
      lang: "en"
      permalink: /:path
```

In brief I need:

- custom variables set for each page in the specified directory globally instead in each page front matter
- make Jekyll to generate all pages from the specified directory to build in the root of _site directory using a global permalink